# Hiding divs and enable on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple rows

```
<div class="row" id="move-data-row0"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

I want only the first three to be shown and on a button click 3 more should appear.

My first thoughts were to give every div the same classname with an index but I do not know how the JavaScript should be implemented.

I started by trying to hide one div, but that doesn't really work

```
$("#move-data-row0").children().prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: You can't disable divs, if you want to hide them, see my answer. Or you want to do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this minimal example, or improve it to get what you really want:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">1</div>
<div class="row">2</div>
<div class="row">3</div>
<div class="row">4</div>
<div class="row">5</div>
<div class="row">6</div>
<div class="row">7</div>
<button>More</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.row:gt(2)').hide();
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.row:hidden:lt(3)').show();
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/e0ppjwnm/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Pretty cool thing with the :gt and :lt, haven't heard of that before... seems to be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome ! And you can find more useful things in the jQuery API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/